# Java: Generics and unchecked - Why?

Tags: java, generics, syntax-error, java-8

I am using **JDK8** and `javac 1.8.0_05`
I have an interface like this:

```java
public interface NumberHolder<N extends Number> {        
    Optional<String> getNumberName();
}
```

As you can see for all sub-types of `NumericHolder` a method `getNumberName()` returns `Optional<String>`.
But... when I try to access that like:

```java
NumberHolder numberHolder = null;
Optional<String> optional = numberHolder.getNumberName(); // warning is here
```

The compiler says:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion 
        Optional<String> optional = numberHolder.getNumberName();
```

But the `getNumberName()` is always `Optional<String>`, so **why is the warning raised?**
Can somebody explain me that?

Comment: I know that declaring `numberHolder` as `NumberHolder<?> numberHolder = null;` helps, but why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of *raw types*, i.e. generic types without specifying a type argument exists for backward compatibility with pre-Generic code only. Therefore, you can’t use generic methods together with a raw type. This is a design decision made when Generics were introduced.

You are using the raw type `NumberHolder` of the generic type `NumberHolder<N extends Number>`. When invoking the method `getNumberName()` on a *raw type*, the generic signature is ignored and an `Optional` (the *raw type* of `Optional<String>`) is used. Then, when assigning the return value of the *raw type* `Optional` to a variable of the generic type `Optional<String>`, a warning is generated.

You don’t need to specify an actual type for the type parameter when you don’t use it. Just changing the declaration of `numberHolder` from `NumberHolder numberHolder` to `NumberHolder<?> numberHolder` would be enough. Then, it is not a *raw type* anymore and the generic signature of its method will be used, making the warning disappear.